# How to make a model with more than 2 input layers for buffering and merging?

Tags: qgis, vector, layers, qgis-modeler

Would it be possible to add more inputs to Buffer and Merge? From what I can see there is a limit of two input layers per both. As far as I know this is possible in ArcGIS's Model Builder but from the looks of it, I can't find it.

My goal is to make a model for pre-processing 5 shapefiles, the goal is to output a single one.

What are my options in this case?

Comment: The **Merge** tool from SAGA or GDAL allows for multiple shapefiles to be merged. Are you looking to buffer 5 shapefiles individually and then merge them all?

Comment: Hi Joseph! Looking to merge them all in the end. So QGIS doesn't have that possibility, I was pretty sure of it. Why doesn't it?

Comment: Ahh I'm guessing you're using the latest _Processing_ plugin which, for some reason, has done away with the Merge tools from SAGA and GDAL. My only advice is to downgrade the _Processing_ plugin to 2.2 which does contain the different Merge tools. You can download the plugin from [here](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/processing/) and unzip the folder to your C:\Users\You\.qgis2\python\plugins directory. Hope this helps a little anyway!

Comment: That's true, I'm using a QGIS 2.8.2, which has pre-installed the latest version of most plugins. Thank you, Joseph, but wouldn't that cause any issues? Last time I tried something similar my whole QGIS installation got busted.

Comment: You can check the **Minimum QGIS version** that's required in the plugin repository (linked in my previous comment). But usually, the latest plugins can become incompatible with older versions of QGIS. But this shouldn't mess up your whole QGIS installation as you can simply replace the plugin folders if a version doesn't work. Saying that, I used version 2.2 of the _Processing_ plugin in QGIS 2.8.2 and seems to work fine so hopefully you won't have any issues =)

Comment: Most welcome buddy! :)